# Overriding scss variables with Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, materialize

I have the following scss file being imported into my Angular Project

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import "./mat-palette.scss";

@include mat-core();

$ombi-app-primary: mat-palette($ombi-primary, 500);
$ombi-app-accent : mat-palette($ombi-accent, A200, A100, A400);

$background: white;

$ombi-app-warn : mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);

$ombi-app-theme: mat-light-theme($ombi-app-primary, $ombi-app-accent, $ombi-app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($ombi-app-theme);

// Define an alternate dark theme.
$ombi-dark-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 800);
$ombi-dark-app-accent: mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$ombi-dark-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($ombi-dark-app-primary, $ombi-dark-app-accent, $ombi-dark-app-warn);

$primary: mat-color($ombi-app-primary);
$accent: mat-color($ombi-app-accent);
$warn: mat-color($ombi-app-warn);

.dark {
    @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
    $panel: mat-color(mat-palette($mat-grey, 800));
    $primary: mat-color($ombi-dark-app-primary);
    $accent: mat-color($ombi-dark-app-accent);
    $warn: mat-color($ombi-dark-app-warn);

    $background:  #424242;
}
```

Now when the `.dark` class is applied to the body I expect it to apply the variables inside the .dark section above.

I am importing this file into other scss files so I can use the variables e.g. `$background`.

So when the `.dark` class is applied, it seems that `$background` is set to `white` and not `#424242` and I cannot work out why.

Here is an example on how I am importing it:

```
@import "~styles/Styles.scss";

.details {
    background: $background;
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably scope - `$background` is defined in the class `.dark` and you are trying to use it in a different class `.details`. Flip things around - 'import' your Styles.scss definitions - `.details` - into `.dark` by way of a mixin.

Comment: @G.Tranter I'm not 100% following what you mean here

Comment: When your Styles.scss is compiled, it will have `.dark { $background:  #424242; } .details { background: $background; }` - separate selector blocks. So .details does not see $background.